# Why firefox doesn't store any information?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-cache

I use firefox 5 on Windows 7. The thing is that firefox doesn't store any login information even though I set to store it. For example, when I use superuser, I have to login every time I visit the site.

What might be wrong? Do I have to change some setup?

Comment: Just a thought,but it might have something to do with your cookies... Are there any sites that FF5 will "remember"?

Comment: FF5 was released in 2011. There have  been several hundreds security updates in this time, you should really upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login is stored in a cookie, [I use Cookie Monster](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/CookieMonster.php) to manage cookies, you can add cookies to the protected list and still delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: Setting Options/Privacy/Remember history solves this issue. Thanks.